# What is the best optimization method for WordPress

Tags: wordpress, optimization

i have a website about the social media which is http://www.vuub.net but my site is very slow and i thought it's about the Theme. How can i reduce to server load time an easy way. I am using WP Super Cache plug-in but still have a problem about the server load time. Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all like the your website look but as you can say, site performance are is not good right now. Here is the some steps before the move for more advancing steps;

1) De-activate all of your plug-ins.
2) Try the use W3 Total Cache instead of WP Super Cache.

After to using this methods come and we can speak again. Also while you are from Turkiye, you can check my web site about more advancing steps about the WordPress and WordPress Optimization; http://www.fatihtoprak.com

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Here are few articles, hope it will helps you,

1. http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/10-quick-tips-optimizing-speeding-up-your-wordpress-site/
2. http://graphpaperpress.com/blog/10-seo-tips-for-wordpress-websites/
3. http://www.inkthemes.com/12-ways-to-optimize-speed-of-large-wordpress-websites/01/

Comment: Thank you very much for the resources, especially tutsplus page is have some awesome informations. :)